# dividing selected columns in pandas

Tags: pandas

This is the dataframe:

```
bins  year  binA  binB  binC  binD  binE  binF  binG  binH
0     1998   4.0   5.0   1.0   1.0   2.0   0.0   1.0   0.0
1     1999   4.0   2.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   4.0   1.0   2.0
2     2000   4.0   1.0   1.0   0.0   4.0   1.0   1.0   2.0
3     2001   2.0   1.0   4.0   1.0   1.0   0.0   2.0   3.0
```

My goal is to divide `binA` through `binH` by sum of `binA:binH` or for row 1998, divide by the sum of the row excluding the year number.

Sum of desired columns:
`newdfdd.loc[:,'binA':'binH'].sum(axis=1)`

To get the desired value this is what I have tried:

```
newdfdd[['binA','binB','binC','binD','binE',
         'binF','binG' ,'binH']].div(newdfdd.loc[:,'binA':'binH'].sum(axis=1))
```

But, I get `NaN` and four extra columns as following:

```
0   1   2   3   binA   binB binC binD binE binF binG binH
0   NaN NaN NaN NaN    NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   NaN NaN NaN NaN    NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   NaN NaN NaN NaN    NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   NaN NaN NaN NaN    NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

I want results in the following format:

```
bins  year   binA  binB  binC  binD  binE  binF  binG  binH
0     1998   0.285 0.357  ...   ....  ....  ....  ...  ...        
1     1999   ..   ..   ..   ..   ..   ..   ..   ..
```

.... means some number from calculation.

What do I need to edit in my code for the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `div` statement you need to provide the `axis='index'` and it should get the result you are looking for.

So your code above should look like:

```
newdfdd.update(newdfdd.loc[:,'binA':'binH'].div(newdfdd.loc[:,'binA':'binH'].sum(axis=1), 
                                                axis='index'))
```

This will compute your percent of row sum as desired and then update the values inplace in the `newfdd` dataframe.

Here is the entirety of my solution for clarity (I used df, and random variables, but the rest is the same):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'bins':[0,1,2,3],
              'year':[1998,1999,2000,2001],
              'binA':np.random.randint(1,10,4),
              'binB':np.random.randint(1,10,4),
              'binC':np.random.randint(1,10,4),
              'binD':np.random.randint(1,10,4),
              'binE':np.random.randint(1,10,4),
              'binF':np.random.randint(1,10,4),
              'binG':np.random.randint(1,10,4),
              'binH':np.random.randint(1,10,4)})

#reodering columns to match your dataframe layout
df = df[['bins','year','binA','binB','binC','binD','binE',
     'binF','binG' ,'binH']]

df.update(df.loc[:,'binA':'binH'].div(df.loc[:,'binA':'binH'].sum(axis=1),axis='index'))

print(df)

   bins year    binA        binB        binC        binD        binE    binF    binG    binH
0   0   1998    0.222222    0.037037    0.148148    0.185185    0.037037    0.111111    0.037037    0.222222
1   1   1999    0.264706    0.058824    0.205882    0.058824    0.029412    0.147059    0.176471    0.058824
2   2   2000    0.166667    0.041667    0.145833    0.020833    0.166667    0.166667    0.145833    0.145833
3   3   2001    0.062500    0.187500    0.020833    0.145833    0.083333    0.166667    0.166667    0.166667
```

Comment: thanks Jtweeder, looks like the year column vanished in your presentation as well.

Comment: vanished as in not included in the calculation? Yes...if that is not what you meant then there may be an error still in your code as the `bins` and `year` should persist in the output as the `update` will only change the columns you provide to it.

Comment: meant  not included as my desired result. sorry

Comment: copy and paste my entire updated solution and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the result you are looking for:

```
df['rowSum'] = df[df.columns[2:]].apply(sum, axis=1)
df[df.columns[2:]].apply(lambda x: (x / x['rowSum']), axis=1).drop(columns=['rowSum'])

        binA        binB        binC        binD        binE       binF     binG        binH
0   0.285714    0.357143    0.071429    0.071429    0.142857    0.000000    0.071429    0.000000
1   0.285714    0.142857    0.071429    0.000000    0.000000    0.285714    0.071429    0.142857
2   0.285714    0.071429    0.071429    0.000000    0.285714    0.071429    0.071429    0.142857
3   0.142857    0.071429    0.285714    0.071429    0.071429    0.000000    0.142857    0.214286
```

Comment: thanks Chris, looks like the year column vanished in your presentation. :-)

Comment: @lpt you can map it back in on the index

Comment: Don't use `apply(sum)`.  That's an antipattern in pandas.  Just use `sum(1)`